# Generating PDF Reports with Pentaho User Console 9.0

Tags: tomcat, pentaho

I have Pentaho Server 9.0 installed on a Linux CentOS 7 VM, I have created some reports in Spanish and publish them into my server.

When I run the reports on the server,requesting a PDF document as output, it deletes all the accented vowels (á, é, í, ó and ú). When I run the report directly on Report Designer it works fine. And when I run the report on the server with HTML output its displayed correctly.

I already read forums with this kind of problem in past versions but their solutions are already applied or are inefficient.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or have any ideas on how to solve them?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

The problem was that the font used in the report wasn't installed on the system.

The problem was solved by copying the TTF file in $JRE/lib/fonts where $JRE is the path your java runtime enviroment is installed.